# Error 'adb: failed to install' when trying to package a simple calculator app with buildozer made using kivy

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to package and install a simple calculator made with kivy on my android phone using buildozer on ubuntu, I keep getting this error after it shows the list of devices attached.

```
adb: failed to install /home/hamzah/Desktop/calc/bin/myapp2-0.1-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk: Performing Streamed Install
# Command failed: /home/hamzah/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb install -r "/home/hamzah/Desktop/calc/bin/myapp2-0.1-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk"
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:.tar=01;31:.tgz=01;31:.arc=01;31:.arj=01;31:.taz=01;31:.lha=01;31:.lz4=01;31:.lzh=01;31:.lzma=01;31:.tlz=01;31:.txz=01;31:.tzo=01;31:.t7z=01;31:.zip=01;31:.z=01;31:.Z=01;31:.dz=01;31:.gz=01;31:.lrz=01;31:.lz=01;31:.lzo=01;31:.xz=01;31:.zst=01;31:.tzst=01;31:.bz2=01;31:.bz=01;31:.tbz=01;31:.tbz2=01;31:.tz=01;31:.deb=01;31:.rpm=01;31:.jar=01;31:.war=01;31:.ear=01;31:.sar=01;31:.rar=01;31:.alz=01;31:.ace=01;31:.zoo=01;31:.cpio=01;31:.7z=01;31:.rz=01;31:.cab=01;31:.wim=01;31:.swm=01;31:.dwm=01;31:.esd=01;31:.jpg=01;35:.jpeg=01;35:.mjpg=01;35:.mjpeg=01;35:.gif=01;35:.bmp=01;35:.pbm=01;35:.pgm=01;35:.ppm=01;35:.tga=01;35:.xbm=01;35:.xpm=01;35:.tif=01;35:.tiff=01;35:.png=01;35:.svg=01;35:.svgz=01;35:.mng=01;35:.pcx=01;35:.mov=01;35:.mpg=01;35:.mpeg=01;35:.m2v=01;35:.mkv=01;35:.webm=01;35:.ogm=01;35:.mp4=01;35:.m4v=01;35:.mp4v=01;35:.vob=01;35:.qt=01;35:.nuv=01;35:.wmv=01;35:.asf=01;35:.rm=01;35:.rmvb=01;35:.flc=01;35:.avi=01;35:.fli=01;35:.flv=01;35:.gl=01;35:.dl=01;35:.xcf=01;35:.xwd=01;35:.yuv=01;35:.cgm=01;35:.emf=01;35:.ogv=01;35:.ogx=01;35:.aac=00;36:.au=00;36:.flac=00;36:.m4a=00;36:.mid=00;36:.midi=00;36:.mka=00;36:.mp3=00;36:.mpc=00;36:.ogg=00;36:.ra=00;36:.wav=00;36:.oga=00;36:.opus=00;36:.spx=00;36:.xspf=00;36:'
#     LC_MEASUREMENT = 'ar_AE.UTF-8'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     LC_PAPER = 'ar_AE.UTF-8'
#     LC_MONETARY = 'ar_AE.UTF-8'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     MANAGERPID = '1661'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     INVOCATION_ID = 'dac14f87552c4eb0ab9d5f4b09a0faea'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     USERNAME = 'hamzah'
#     XDG_VTNR = '2'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     LC_NAME = 'ar_AE.UTF-8'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = '2'
#     USER = 'hamzah'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     TEXTDOMAINDIR = '/usr/share/locale/'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/530d5beb_695f_4489_aa27_f28c9e09f5dc'
#     PWD = '/home/hamzah/Desktop/calc'
#     HOME = '/home/hamzah'
#     JOURNAL_STREAM = '9:47931'
#     TEXTDOMAIN = 'im-config'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1823'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     LC_ADDRESS = 'ar_AE.UTF-8'
#     DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=5ebf0f2869dfa7664f769f1c603f5c0b'
#     LC_NUMERIC = 'ar_AE.UTF-8'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     WINDOWPATH = '2'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     VTE_VERSION = '5202'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '2'
#     DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE = 'session'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.70'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     LC_TELEPHONE = 'ar_AE.UTF-8'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     LOGNAME = 'hamzah'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=5ebf0f2869dfa7664f769f1c603f5c0b'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     PATH = '/home/hamzah/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/hamzah/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     LC_IDENTIFICATION = 'ar_AE.UTF-8'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/hamzah-virtual-machine:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1726,unix/hamzah-virtual-machine:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1726'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     LC_TIME = 'ar_AE.UTF-8'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/hamzah/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/hamzah/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/hamzah/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
#     ANDROID_SERIAL = '9WV7N18401026053'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

[changed update settings to display immediately](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3yHW.png)

Error only comes up when the mobile is connected.

Answer (score 0):

This just means you haven't turned on `USB Debugging` on your mobile. Just go to your mobile settings then to developer settings and `turn on` `"USB Debugging"`.

Comment: Got it ! i had it turned on but still turning off and on again worked thanks a lot.

Comment: If that helped please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so that others can see it too.